# Why is the perfect obstructor the perfect conductor as Heaviside 'believed'?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

How might one consider a conductor to be an 'obstructor'?

Might the strength of the 'skin effect' of a conductor be in direct relation to conductance?

And how does this relate to insulators, as these material are literal obstructors to energy transfer.. Might electricity flow at full strength along the surface instead of through the insulator such as along the inside of wire insulation?

Answer (score 2):

A conductor can serve to obstruct:

- AC via the [skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), where AC would create changing magnetic fields that in turn, act against currents in the bulk but enforces currents near the surface (insulators do not do that),
- external electric field, since the mobile charge carriers react to them, and redistribute to prevent the field from penetrating deeper into the bulk.

However, note that skin effect is an AC phenomenon. DC can still flow through a perfect conductor, for example, in superconducting magnets.

In ordinary insulators, there is very little current flowing through, in the bulk and at the surface. However, this does not mean that insulators cannot conduct power. For example, fiber optics (and in general dielectric waveguides) can carry electromagnetic power across great distances.

(Edit: typo and rewording)

Comment: I appreciate your guidance, as you evidently know what it is you're talking about. But I was looking for a description of conductors from the perspective of the cause of the effects it relates to the understanding heaviside, tesla, or steinmetz would've had. Although your statements have still been quite helpful.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question fully. Are you asking, "We're given that a perfect conductor is a perfect obstructor that blocks (AC) currents in the bulk, and conducts them on the surface. An insulator also blocks current in the bulk, so is it plausible that it conduct current on the surface?"?

Comment: Skin effect occurs because alternating current through a conductor induces a changing magnetic field around the conductor, which in turn induces eddy currents that cancel current in the bulk but enforces those in the surface. Note that this is redistribution of total current. But for the insulator case, you start with no total current to start with, so there's nothing to redistribute.

Comment: Meanwhile, another way for insulator to conduct AC is through displacement current (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current). This explains why in electronics, a capacitor can transmit AC, even though its bulk is an insulating dielectric.